# What is the solution to these SDP?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I am in trouble with my homework, the quesetion is to solve a pair of stochastic differential equation.

$dX_t^1 = X_t^2dt + \alpha dB_t^1$

$dX_t^2 = -X_t^1dt + \beta dB_t^2$

$\alpha \ and \ \beta$ are constants, $B_t^1, B_t^2$ are independent standard Brownian Motion

I have tried my best to solve them, I guess I need to multiply a integrating factor, but I can not find it.

Comment: Are you after identities such as $$X^1_t=\alpha\cos t\int_0^t\cos(s)dB^1_s+\alpha\sin t\int_0^t\sin(s)dB^1_s-\beta\cos t\int_0^t\sin(s)dB^2_s+\beta\sin t\int_0^t\cos(s)dB^2_s,$$ or some equivalent representation?